# How to get YouTube channel statistics like last 28 days using data api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get last 28 days youtube channel statistics like

1. Total view
2. avg daily views
3. channel country
4. views last 28 days
5. avg daily subscriber
6. List item

I am get all other thing but these not.

currently I am using this

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=PBrEq9Wd6_U&key=[API_KEY]&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=PBrEq9Wd6_U&key=%5BAPI_KEY%5D&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status)

and response received

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "xdV7ewWgCsOTS7cf0XUF8Fp9Xg4",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "dZDlRrNH8pJOOeV8rPpuQcUaeKU",
      "id": "PBrEq9Wd6_U",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-10-20T16:00:12Z",
        "channelId": "UC5DNytAJ6_FISueUfzZCVsw",
        "title": "Candy Crush in React",
        "description": "In this video I show you how to make a game of Candy Crush in React!\n\n00:00 Introduction\n01:37 Setting up our project\n07:25 Creating our Game Board\n24:48 Checking for matches\n42:46 Moving Candies down\n48:42 Dragging and Dropping in React\n01:07:20 Adding Images in React\n01:11:43 Adding the score\n01:17:25 Checking for blanks\n01:19:23 Suggestions for refactoring\n01:20:00 Where to go next? Saving High Scores (https://youtu.be/ARL0NuIQNjY)\n\nFinal code available here: https://github.com/kubowania/candy-crush-reactjs\nLearn how to add Game State in a database: https://youtu.be/ARL0NuIQNjY\n___\n⭐ Use promo code ANIAKUBOW for 3 months free of WebStorm IDE here (I get no commission from this link, but am in a partnership): https://jb.gg/get_webstorm\n\n⭐ New to code and none of this is making sense? Watch my '12hr+ YouTube Coding Bootcamp' in which you will learn HTML, CSS and JavaScript Fundamentals completely from scratch. It's on my channel and its 100% free.\n\n⭐ In most videos I use Tabnine as my A.I autocompletion tool. You can download it for free here (I get no commission from this link, but am in a partnership): ",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PBrEq9Wd6_U/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PBrEq9Wd6_U/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PBrEq9Wd6_U/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "standard": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PBrEq9Wd6_U/sddefault.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480
          },
          "maxres": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PBrEq9Wd6_U/maxresdefault.jpg",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Code with Ania Kubów",
        "tags": [
          "candy crush",
          "react tutorial",
          "react game",
          "gamedev",
          "software engineering",
          "software development",
          "learn to code",
          "coding bootamp",
          "100daysOfcode",
          "javascript tutorial for beginners",
          "javascript tutorial",
          "react for beginners",
          "candy crush development"
        ],
        "categoryId": "27",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "localized": {
          "title": "Candy Crush in React",
          "description": "In this video I show you how to make a game of Candy Crush in React!\n\n00:00 Introduction\n01:37 Setting up our project\n07:25 Creating our Game Board\n24:48 Checking for matches\n42:46 Moving Candies down\n48:42 Dragging and Dropping in React\n01:07:20 Adding Images in React\n01:11:43 Adding the score\n01:17:25 Checking for blanks\n01:19:23 Suggestions for refactoring\n01:20:00 Where to go next? Saving High Scores (https://youtu.be/ARL0NuIQNjY)\n\nFinal code available here: https://github.com/kubowania/candy-crush-reactjs\nLearn how to add Game State in a database: https://youtu.be/ARL0NuIQNjY\n___\n⭐ Use promo code ANIAKUBOW for 3 months free of WebStorm IDE here (I get no commission from this link, but am in a partnership): https://jb.gg/get_webstorm\n\n⭐ New to code and none of this is making sense? Watch my '12hr+ YouTube Coding Bootcamp' in which you will learn HTML, CSS and JavaScript Fundamentals completely from scratch. It's on my channel and its 100% free.\n\n⭐ In most videos I use Tabnine as my A.I autocompletion tool. You can download it for free here (I get no commission from this link, but am in a partnership):"
        },
        "defaultAudioLanguage": "en-GB"
      },
      "contentDetails": {
        "duration": "PT1H21M1S",
        "dimension": "2d",
        "definition": "hd",
        "caption": "false",
        "licensedContent": true,
        "contentRating": {},
        "projection": "rectangular"
      },
      "status": {
        "uploadStatus": "processed",
        "privacyStatus": "public",
        "license": "youtube",
        "embeddable": true,
        "publicStatsViewable": true,
        "madeForKids": false
      },
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "150594",
        "likeCount": "5017",
        "favoriteCount": "0",
        "commentCount": "232"
      }
    }
  ],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you can't request to YouTube Data API v3 data from the past. However by regularly retrieving the data from YouTube you will be able in the future to get these statistics.

1. *total view*: use [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) make sure to include `statistics` in `part`.
2. *avg daily views*: I let you do the math after having retrieved regularly the data you need.
3. *channel country*: AFAIK channel country isn't defined on all YouTube channel however if it is defined you can get it in the `snippet` `part` by using [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)
4. *views last 28 days*: I let you do the math
5. *avg daily subscriber*: You can retrieve the `subscriberCount` by using [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) if you use `statistics` in `part`. Warning: it is known that this number is rounded by YouTube and AFAIK there isn't any way to get a more accurate counter
6. *list item*: I don't understand what you mean, can you add precision as a comment and I'll edit my answer? Do you mean listing your videos?

Comment: I am creating an application, where user can check all details like SUBSCRIBERS FOR THE LAST 30 DAYS,  VIDEO VIEWS FOR THE LAST 30 DAYS,  ESTIMATED MONTHLY EARNING of any YouTube channel by Channel id

Comment: Yes ok so you'll need a backend to your app. However I don't understand the point you are trying to make me understand with your comment.

Comment: I am creating only frontend app to fetch these data by channel id only

Comment: It seems to be impossible then. It seems clear that you need a backend.

Comment: all data get from YouTube api then why should I create ?

Comment: I can't understand your sentence. If you still don't understand why you need a backend for having statistics for the lasr n days, then I can't help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the YouTube [Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/). What you seek would be classed under [Metrics](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics).

Also, you can check the video about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtsS8sEzEeY