# Getting monthly view counts of any YouTube video's

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the Youtube Data API to access the total viewCount of a video.

However, I would like to see the monthly views of a video based on a specific date and/or time. For example, video A currently has a viewCount of 500,000 at the current date and time but perhaps a month ago it had a viewCount of 400,000. Is it possible to access that previous value?

Is there any Youtube API method or alternative resource that would allow me to access the previous view count of a video/list of videos for any public channel?

Thank you!

Comment: Feels duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/q/70389338/7123660

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get YouTube channel statistics like last 28 days using data api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70389338/how-to-get-youtube-channel-statistics-like-last-28-days-using-data-api)