# Historical YouTube Trending videos by date and country

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, dataset, youtube-data-api

I am looking for a way to get top-50 most popular videos from [Explore Tab](https://www.youtube.com/feed/explore) for a specific date or a period of time for a specific country. Can't find a way how to do it in YouTube API Documentation. Is there a way? If not, maybe you know some workarounds for getting a historical data?

For example, I could build a web scraper that would collect trending videos from [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.youtube.com/feed/explore) but it shows trending videos in the U.S. only.
Also, found [YouTube Charts website](https://charts.youtube.com/), but it shows only music.

Comment: Just to make sure, you're trying to get trending videos metadata from the past ? Trending videos metadata since today don't interest you ? Otherwise the answered method from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70389338/how-to-get-youtube-channel-statistics-like-last-28-days-using-data-api might interest you.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison I am looking for the trending videos that were in the Trending Tab in a specific date, e.g. 50 videos from Trending on 2021-01-01 in Canada. I can get the current 50 videos using this API request: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=CA&maxResults=50&key=API_KEY. However, I need the same information from the past.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such public endpoint or public resource to get these results - besides Wayback Machine and the public/official YouTube channels you can find on their website.

However, since you mentioned using Wayback Machine, you *could* follow these steps:

1. Enter to Wayback Machine and search for results about the [Pouplar on YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCF0pVplsI8R5kcAqgtoRqoA) - see example of [extract from Jun 15, 2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20210615065106/https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCF0pVplsI8R5kcAqgtoRqoA)<sup>1</sup>.
2. Retrieve the videos shown in the search results from step 1.

That being said, I recommend you to start creating a database for record trending videos everyday - not sure how you can do this by region, though (*this is due there are trending videos by "main countries" like UK, India, some parts of Asia, France*, but, as I searched, trending applies for ***ALL*** countries) - if I'm wrong in this, please, let me know.

Another possible way to get close results to your expectations could be:

1. Enter to [Popular on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCF0pVplsI8R5kcAqgtoRqoA/featured) channel and check the [Popular now](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-) playlist.<sup>2</sup>
2. Retrieve those results and organize the results - with this, I mean: check the publication date, check the channel's country/location, etc. It's up to you to check how to organize the available data.

---

<sup>1</sup> Please check that probably there is no data/snapshot on a given day you require - using Wayback Machine -.

<sup>2</sup> According to the updated date, this playlist is updated everyday, so, you have to make the same procedure mentioned above (*create a database that store results everyday, etc.*).

Not sure if with an VPN you can set the VPN and try to get the "Popular now" videos from the selected VPN country, might worth give it a try.

Try also [contact with YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/trends/contact/) - probably you *might* get some sort of answer, ask them if they can provide information about trending videos from a specific region - in a specific time.

Comment: Note that there isn't any need to use a VPN of a given country as you can just choose it by clicking on `⋮` at the top-right of the YouTube UI and then click on `Location`.