# YouTube API, retrieve influencers historical data

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm new to using YouTube API and I'm struggling with the conflicting language, thought I would just ask the question here:

I'm looking to get the historical data for a selection of YouTube channels (not my own). The main data I would like is the daily subscribers gained (or just the sub count on a select day).
Really all I want is to retrieve historical data any help in any language would be amazing (my primary language is python)

Comment: Your question looks similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70389338).

Answer (score 2):

The data you are looking for does not exist.  You may be able to get something like that from the YouTube analytics api but only if you are the owner of the channel.

The YouTube data api is not going to give you any historical stats.  I actually dont think it will give you any stats at all unless you are the authorized owner of the channel.

Comment: Yeah I did think that at one point but then I found some people with 2 years worth of data, plus why would the sub count for an account be secret when anyone can go view the count at the moment.
So I'm sure there is a way, and I have seen comments in their youtube API docs that talk about historic data with 30 day delay

Comment: apologies I didn't read your bio, okay thank you for sharing that knowledge with me