# How to get watched history of a music video on youtube using YouTube api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on a music project and i will like to view the watched history of different music videos on youtube that are not on my channel.

A typical case is this [music chart site](https://chartex.com/song-statistics/eW91dHViZS1RXzZPWmQ2RkZZZw==)

I have been exploring youtube but i cant see any endpoint for that.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs

I have also check analytics API but it seems like it only works on videos on your channel
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query

Is there any way to do this or an alternative?
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for an API endpoint to retrieve the data at [this link](https://www.youtube.com/feed/history) ?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison No, I need something i can get for example weekly, daily or monthly views of a video. 

This  [Youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query) seems to work  but only for videos on your channel

Comment: @BenjaminLoison, do you think is possible to get this data

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to respond, you may find your answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70389338/how-to-get-youtube-channel-statistics-like-last-28-days-using-data-api).

Comment: @BenjaminLoison It seems like is not possible directly

Comment: Correct [as @DaImTo also agrees on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73266604/7123660).