# YouTube Data API V3 How to get last 24 hours views count of a video

Tags: api, youtube

Is it possible to get last 24 hours views count of a video from YouTube Data API V3.

I tried the following url, I only get total views but not views by day.

If it is not possible, just want to know how did Vidiq chrome addon shows the last 24hour views.

Any advice is appreciated

I tried using the following code

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos part=contentDetails,statistics,snippet&id=QicO1Gd0kvU&key={apiKey}
```

But i get only total views, not daily views of the video

Comment: Similar to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70389338).

Comment: ok Thanks for the reply @BenjaminLoison but how vidiq chrome addon get that 24 hour metrics?

Comment: They might use a backend which every hour get the metrics you would request later on, as explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70392962) and comments.