# YouTube API - get most watched videos for a given week

Tags: youtube-api

I'm wondering if it is possible to use YouTube's API to find the most viewed videos each week. Ideally, the request would also yield the subscriber count from the channel that hosts the video as well as the language. Is this possible?

Comment: Looks similar to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70389338/7123660).

Comment: The linked post is about looking at the views / subscriber count for a given channel. I'm looking for a method, across the entirety of YouTube, to find the most popular videos for a given week. (Ideally also grabbing the subscriber count for the associated channel).

Comment: Maybe this point was indeed missing: I don't think that there is any way to retrieve an arbitrary number of most viewed videos each week (if any depending on how the `Popular Right Now` playlist works), you can see [@Marco Aurelio Fernandez Reyes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75632187) that is the nearest thing you are interested in that I am aware of. If you want to monitor only a given set of channels, then consider the method mentioned in the link I firstly gave.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to retrieve the most popular videos for a given week/day/etc.

However, you *could* retrieve the current most popular videos by querying the videos stored on the [*Popular Right Now* playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-):

You could build your own database by querying this playlist each day and feeding your database.

Notice that, even when this playlist is updated every day, a video can still appear for more than one day.

I tried search in [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-), but, there is not daily snapshots and I don't see if there is an alternative for get the playlist's history.