# How can I get history subscriber count in Youtube? E.g. How to see what is the subscriber count at the end of 2022 vs 2023

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, data-science, data-analysis, youtube-data-api

Apologies, if my question is unclear as I am new to this space.

I am trying to do a data analysis project for my portfolio about youtube channel.

I would like to compare the youtube channel growth over the years.

Is there anyway to get history data?

I can only get the current subscriber count when I call the API.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list

Comment: Are you considering a channel you have access to or a channel from a random person?

Comment: I am considering to analyze channel from a random person. E.g. Luke Barousse (https://www.youtube.com/@LukeBarousse)

Comment: Then your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70389338).

Comment: I see, seems like it is not possible then. Thanks for the link!