# How do I get all this data for youtube channels?

Tags: web-scraping, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am building a youtube tool and I need this data so I can use it in my tool.
I will need:

- Channel subscribers (as on a particular date)
- Channel subscriber growth (during a particular period)
- Views on a channel (during a particular period)
- List of videos published during a particular time along with their public data (views, likes, shares, comments)
  (I DO NOT NEED THIS DATA FOR A SINGLE YOUTBE CHANNEL, I NEED IT FOR ANY CHANNEL INPUTTED BY THE USER)

I have checked socialBlade and apify actors but they do not fulfill my needs. Can anyone tell me any platforms or any possible paid or unpaid tool/API that I can use in my project.

Thank You

Comment: Concerning the historical aspect, related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70389338).

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not include detailed information about how you want to access, store or need the data.

YouTube provides a very useful API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs?hl=en

You can easily gain access with a Google account and use Python or other programming languages to retrieve the data you need.