# Accessing past Public data via the YouTube data API without Authentication

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

Can I get a specific YouTube channel's or video's publicly available stats from like 1 month or 1 week before without any authentication process or Oauth.

I tried the YouTube API but I am only able to get present data from it. I want to access the data from past in order to show stats on my web app.

Comment: Similar [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70389338).